# When an installer is optimising code, what is it actually doing?

Tags: windows, installation, performance

Some installers, such as Toad's, perform a "code optimization" during the installation of the program, presumably to enhance the operation of the application.

However, considering installers usually contain pre-compiled executables, what is the installer actually doing during this optimization process?

Comment: Is the program built on top of .NET (e.g. C#)? Those are compiled to CLR, optimization via _ngen_ would compile them to native machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Those tools call [ngen.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which converts the DLL from IL mode to an DLL which is optimized for the CPU architecture. When this is done, the [JustInTime Compiling (JIT)](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation) is no longer needed and speeds up .net applications a lot.